# How can I find elements for native android app on Windows as Windows Appium inspector doesn't work?

Tags: windows, automation, appium, appium-android

I am working on Appium on Windows 7. As Appium Inspector does not work on Windows, what is the alternate way to find elements?

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) to use Google's `uiautomatorviewer` which is what Appium's [tutorial](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#uiautomatorviewer) suggests you use.

Comment: Hi @sheeptest...how to let uiautomatorviewer to fetch xpaths? Is there any alternatives to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIAutomatorviewer to find elements. if you have Android SDK installed it can be launched by entering "uiautomatorviewer" in CMD.
D

Answer (score 0):

You can now make use of `Appium Inspector` on **Windows** as well.

Source: https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-exe